# how to save multiple rows in SQL using XML?

Tags: asp.net, sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

I have following XML, and i wish to save its data in my SQL table. I have a table named as tblDummy it has three columns "JobID" "ItemID" "SubitemID". there can be multiple subitemsid for particular combination of Jobid and Itemid. How can i do this?

```
<jobs>
   <job>
     <jobid>4711</jobid>
     <items>
     <itemid>1</itemid>
       <subitems>
        <subitemid>1</subitemid>
        <subitemid>2</subitemid>
       </subitems>
    <itemid>2</itemid>
       <subitems>
        <subitemid>7</subitemid>
        <subitemid>10</subitemid>
       </subitems>
    <itemid>9</itemid>
       <subitems>
        <subitemid>12</subitemid>
        <subitemid>16</subitemid>
       </subitems>
    </items>
   </job>  
 </jobs>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your problem? Writing a loop? Instantiating a connection to db? SQL syntax? Parsing the xml?

Comment: in previous question i asked about how to save xml data in DB if i have only one repeating column behalf of another column. but here i have one repeating column, whose value can repeat for particular combination of other two columns. so help me if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this XML is, you cannot properly parse it. You would need to change it - you should put each item with its `itemid` and subitems into a separate `<item>` node - otherwise you just have a long list of `<itemid>` and `<subitems>` nodes under your `<items>` main node, but you have no means of telling which `<itemid>` and `<subitems>` nodes belong together ....

You need to change your XML to be something like this:

```
<job>
   <jobid>4711</jobid>
   <items>
      <item>
         <itemid>1</itemid>
         <subitems>
             <subitemid>1</subitemid>
             <subitemid>2</subitemid>
         </subitems>
      </item>   
      <item>
         <itemid>2</itemid>
          <subitems>
            ......
          </subitems>
      </item>   
      ... (possibly more <item> nodes) ....
   </items>
</job>
```

**THEN** you could use basically the same code I had for your previous question - extended to cover three levels:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SaveJobs (@input XML)
AS BEGIN

;WITH JobsData AS
(    
    SELECT
        JobID = JobNode.value('(jobid)[1]', 'int'),
        ItemID = ItemNode.value('(itemid)[1]', 'int'),
        SubItemID = SubItemNode.value('.', 'int')
    FROM 
        @input.nodes('/jobs/job') AS TblJobs(JobNode)
    CROSS APPLY
        JobNode.nodes('items/item') AS TblItems(ItemNode)
    CROSS APPLY
        ItemNode.nodes('subitems/subitem') AS TblSubItems(SubItemNode)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.tblDummy(JobID, ItemID, SubItemID)
   SELECT JobID, ItemID, SubItemID
   FROM JobsData
END
```

Basically, you need three "lists" of XML nodes:

- first you need the list of all `<jobs>/<job>` nodes to get the `jobid` values
- for each of those job nodes, you will also need to get their list of nested `<items>/<item>` to get the `itemid` value
- from each  node, you then also get the list of `<subitems>/<subitem>`

This will most likely work - but most likely, it will be rather slow (three nested calls to the `.nodes()` function!).

**Update:**

OK, so the first call `@input.nodes('/jobs/job') AS TblJobs(JobNode)` basically creates a "pseudo" table `TblJobs` with a single column `JobNode` and each `<job>` element in your XML is being stored into a row in that pseudo table - so the first row will contain this XML in it's `JobNode` column:

```
<job>
   <jobid>4711</jobid>
   <items>
      <item>
         <itemid>1</itemid>
         <subitems>
             <subitemid>1</subitemid>
             <subitemid>2</subitemid>
         </subitems>
      </item>   
      <item>
         <itemid>2</itemid>
          <subitems>
            ......
          </subitems>
      </item>   
      ... (possibly more <item> nodes) ....
   </items>
</job>
```

and each further row will contain the additional XML fragments for each subsequent `<job>` element inside `<jobs>`

From each of those XML fragments, the second call

```
CROSS APPLY JobNode.nodes('items/item') AS TblItems(ItemNode)
```

again selects a list of XML fragments into a pseudo table (`TblItems`) with a single column `ItemNode` that contains the XML fragment for each `<item>` node inside that `<job>` node we're dealing with currently.

So the first row in this pseudo-table contains:

```
     <item>
         <itemid>1</itemid>
         <subitems>
             <subitemid>1</subitemid>
             <subitemid>2</subitemid>
         </subitems>
      </item>
```

and the second row will contain

```
      <item>
         <itemid>2</itemid>
          <subitems>
            ......
          </subitems>
      </item>
```

and so on.

And then the third call - you've guessed it - again extracts a list of XML elements as rows into a pseudo-table - one entry for each `<subitem>` node in your XML fragment.

**Update #2**:

> *I'm new to "JobID = JobNode.value('(jobid)[1]', 'int')" line of code*

OK - given the `<Job>` XML fragment that you have:

```
<job>
   <jobid>4711</jobid>
   <items>
     ......
   </items>
</job>
```

the `.value()` call just executes this XPath expression (`jobid`) on that XML and basically gets back the `<jobid>4711</jobid>` snippet. It then extracts the **value** of that node (the inner text), and the second parameter of the `.value()` call defines what SQL data type to interpret this as - so it basically grabs the `4711` from the `<jobid>` node and interprets it as an `int`

Comment: here is an openxml function in sql, could we use this function for the same?

Comment: @ADSinghKamboj: that's *old* and legacy code - I wouldn't use it. Much more complicated, needs to hang on to extra memory chunks etc - and it doesn't make anything easier, either....

Comment: could you please explain above StoreP briefly,  i don't wanna just copy and paste it to run my application, i wish to know its working, please explain it briefly if you could..Thanx.

Comment: @ADSinghKamboj: I did! See the points below the code - that explains how the code works. Or what else do you need to know? Basically you take in a XML snippet, you "shred" it into pieces, and insert those pieces into a relational table

Comment: @ADSinghKamboj: updated my response - tried to explain in more detail what is being done in the calls to the `.nodes()` XQuery function. Does that make sense now?

Comment: thanx a lot marc. I'm new to "JobID = JobNode.value('(jobid)[1]', 'int')" line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a composite key of Jobid and Itemid as primary key.